# Android - Override textAppearance of Small , Medium , Large

Tags: android, styles

i'm trying to override the default text appearance in my android app

This is my styles.xml but its not working ( For textView , picker etc...)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>

  <style name="newTheme" parent="newTheme.Base"></style>

  <style name="newTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

  </style>

  <style name="TextAppearance.Large" parent="newTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
  </style>

  <style name="TextAppearance.Medium" parent="newTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
  </style>

  <style name="TextAppearance.Small" parent="newTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
  </style>


</resources>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Large" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large">
  <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Medium" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium">
  <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Small" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
  <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
</style>
```

Keep in mind, to see your changes you'll have to either refer to them in the layout

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Small"/>
```

or refer to them in the style

```
<style name="newTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="android:textAppearanceLarge">@style/TextAppearance.Large</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmall">@style/TextAppearance.Small</item>

</style>
```